# How can I find telegram user by id

Tags: api, bots, telegram

I'm using telegram bot and can get user id from incoming message.
Sometimes I want to find users who communicate with telegram bot and write them message by myself.
I have only user id and have not some additional information about the user.

Can I somehow find users by id or anonimity with only id available is by design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least what I've been using...

**Program your bot to send you a message with link to that user.**
This can be done by using link in your message (must be used as message entity or inline keyboard button):

```
tg://user?id=<user_id>
```

Or in case you are using MarkdownV2 for formatting

```
[inline mention of a user](tg://user?id=<user_id>)
```

Then, by clicking on that link, you will open a user profile, where you can message your target.

*Note,* user can change his privacy settings, and disable mentions. In this case these links will not work.

Comment: does not work for me, telegram application show just main page when link is opened

Comment: Yeah the same for me